# What is the purpose of the for loop in copying an array?

Tags: c#, for-loop

The code below works but I don't understand why there is a need to use a for loop to copy an array. Is there another way to copy an array without using for loop? This code was taken from here:

https://starboundsoftware.com/books/c-sharp/try-it-out/copying-an-array

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace CopyingAnArray
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create the initial array.
            int[] numbers = new int[] { 4, 5, 2, 3, 1, 0, 8, 9, 7, 6 };

            // Note that while you can do this, this doesn't make a
            // copy. They'll both be the exact same array. Modifying
            // one will affect the other. For more about this, see
            // the chapter on value and reference types.
            // int[] copy = numbers;

            // Copy the values from one array to a copy.
            int[] copy = new int[numbers.Length];
            for (int index = 0; index < numbers.Length; index++)
            {
                copy[index] = numbers[index];
            }

            // Print out the original array.
            for (int index = 0; index < numbers.Length; index++)
            {
                Console.Write(numbers[index] + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

            // Print out the copy.
            for (int index = 0; index < copy.Length; index++)
            {
                Console.Write(copy[index] + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the comments in the code explain what each loop does? Only one loop does the copying. The other two loops prints out the original and the copied array.

Comment: Copying the array only takes one loop. So the answer is: yes, you can easily do it with less than three loops, as your own example shows.

Comment: the example probably should have included console writes regarding the steps, and ordered steps as print the first array, copy the array, and then print the copied array.. but that's hardly relative to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the first loop copies the contents of `number` into a new array. The other two loops are for printing the contents of `numbers` and then `copy` arrays respectively.

You don't have to use a for loop to clone an array. There are alternatives to achieve the same thing. 3 of them come to my mind, where the first one seems to be the best since you can have both the declaration and initialization in a single line.

```
    int[] numbers = new int[] { 4, 5, 2, 3, 1, 0, 8, 9, 7, 6 };

    // Create a clone using LinQ:
    // as @BrettCaswell pointed out,
    // Select() is not required since we are not modifying, manipulating or filtering the elements.
    // .ToArray() would do.
    // int[] copyOfNumbersWithLinQ = numbers.Select(a => a).ToArray();
    int[] copyOfNumbersWithLinQ = numbers.ToArray();

    // Copy using Array.Copy():
    int[] copyOfNumbersWithArrayCopy = new int[numbers.Length];
    Array.Copy(numbers, copyOfNumbersWithArrayCopy, numbers.Length);

    // Copy using numbers.CopyTo()
    int[] copyOfNumbersWithCopyTo = new int[numbers.Length];
    numbers.CopyTo(copyOfNumbersWithCopyTo, 0);
```

Comment: note that `.Select` does not regard Cloning any differently then any loop.  In this scenario `int[]` is a collection of a value types, so it isn't necessary to project with select.. just do `.ToArray()`;  If numbers was a collection of a referential type, you would still being referencing to the same instance with `.Select`.  you would have to actually construct new instances or Clone here.

Comment: here is a csharpfiddle to demonstrate that https://dotnetfiddle.net/OnBabM

Comment: @BrettCaswell You are right. `Select()` is unnecessary. _"If numbers was a collection of a referential type, you would still being referencing to the same instance with .Select"_ But wouldn't you still have the same pointers with `ToArray()` too if the element type had been a reference type? Why confining your concern with an array of reference types to `.Select` only?

Comment: yes, the pointers are still a concern with just `.ToArray()` usage, as well as all these other ArrayCopy methods.  I made the comment\note in regards to `.Select` having been present in your answer as well as the commented out comment in your snippet 'creating a clone using Linq'.  Because cloning, ShallowCloning, DeepCloning have been a point of confusion with expressions.  perhaps a bit in reflection on my own misunderstandings at earlier points :)

Comment: @BrettCaswell I completely agree with you. If the element type had been a reference type, my answer and comments would be different of course. But it is nice of you for bringing up these topics which, I hope, will trigger the release of further research hormones by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

In fact putting it into a single loop would change the printing order.

In the example you presented the original array is printed first, then the copy is printed.

If you put everything into a single loop you would print 1 number of the original array, 1 of the copy, another number of the original array,   another number of the copy etc...

Just try changing the code and see for yourself what happens.

Answer (score 0):

[Array.Copy()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy?view=netframework-4.6.2) can also be used to copy the array